# Can I make expandable/collapsable sections in CodeRunner?

Tags: c++, treeview, workflow, coderunner

I've been using **CodeRunner 2** for a while and I was wondering, in order to optimize my workflow, if it's possible to make a treeview-like division within the code. In other words, being able to *collapse* what I'm not working on while *expanding* what's being used at the moment.

I apologize if it's a menial question, I'm still learning and I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: are you asking if you can code fold?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible in Coderunner. I've never used it, but I did some research and the reviews mentioned that Coderunner did not feature code folding. Perhaps search for a different IDE that does? I know Eclipse features code folding for Windows and I assume it does the same for Mac.

Comment: It seems that it's really unavailable in this app, sadly. I just downloaded Atom by curiosity and, voilà, it makes all the work by itself.

I'll leave a suggestion to the developers, though, as I really enjoy it, but I'll be transitioning for now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Atoms pretty great. No problem! Happy coding!